# JavaMail SEARCH returns BADCHARSET

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have developed an email client at work using JavaMail. Some customers have reported massive delays when searching for subjects with non-English characters (e.g. "Kühlgut").

It turned out that some mail providers (in this case Office 365) do not support searching with UTF-8 charset (resulting in a BadCommandException). Therefore, JavaMail fetches and performs the search locally (as fallback).

This behaviour caused the massive delays.

Code:

```
String searchTerm = "Kühlgut";
SearchTerm[] searchTerms = new SearchTerm[3];
searchTerms[0] = new FromStringTerm(searchTerm);
searchTerms[1] = new SubjectTerm(searchTerm);
searchTerms[2] = new BodyTerm(searchTerm);

OrTerm orTerm = new OrTerm(searchTerms);
folder.search(orTerm);
```

JavaMail debug output of the search command:

```
C18 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 OR OR FROM {8+}
KÃ¼hlgut SUBJECT {8+}
KÃ¼hlgut BODY {8+}
KÃ¼hlgut ALL
C18 NO [BADCHARSET (US-ASCII)] The specified charset is not supported.
C19 SEARCH CHARSET Cp1252 OR OR FROM {7+}
Kühlgut SUBJECT {7+}
Kühlgut BODY {7+}
Kühlgut ALL
C19 NO [BADCHARSET (US-ASCII)] The specified charset is not supported.

B20 FETCH 1 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
* 1 FETCH (ENVELOPE ....)
B20 OK FETCH completed.
B21 FETCH 1 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 1 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ...
B21 OK FETCH completed.
```

I do have two questions:

1. Is it possible to check if the IMAP server supports searching with UTF-8 charset (e.g. via capabilities)?
2. How can I stop JavaMail from fetching all emails if the former is not possible (no exception is thrown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do #1, but for #2 try setting the [`mail.imap.throwsearchexception`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.throwsearchexception) property to true.

And submit a bug to Microsoft since Office 365 really should support searching with utf-8.

Comment: Setting the property mail.imap.throwsearchexception to true worked for me.